# Android - TextView not changing text

Tags: android, textview

I'm currently learning some android for a school project and I can't figure out the way to set text dynamically to a TextView.

Here is the full activity:

```
package com.avilyne.android.gcmclient;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.app.Activity;
import android.app.AlertDialog;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.view.Menu;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.AdapterView;
import android.widget.AdapterView.OnItemClickListener;
import android.widget.ArrayAdapter;
import android.widget.EditText;
import android.widget.ListView;
import android.widget.TextView;
import android.content.DialogInterface;

public class EnviarMensaje extends Activity {
    ListView l; 
    EditText t;
    TextView err;
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_enviar_mensaje);

        l = (ListView)findViewById(R.id.listaVista);    
        t = (EditText)findViewById(R.id.editText1);
        err = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.textoss);
        err.setText("Escriba su mensaje y luego seleccione el canal.");
        l.setOnItemClickListener(new OnItemClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> arg0, View arg1, int arg2, long arg3) {
                String m= t.getText().toString();
                if(m.equals("")){
                    err.setText("Escriba su mensaje y luego seleccione el canal.");
                    return;
                }
                else{
                    showAlert();
                    (new Funciones()).EnviarMensaje(l.getItemAtPosition(arg2).toString(), m);
                    //mostrar mensaje Su mensaje ha sido enviado
                    Intent activityChangeIntent = new Intent(EnviarMensaje.this, FirstActivity.class);
                    EnviarMensaje.this.startActivity(activityChangeIntent);
                }
            }
        });


        ListView lv;
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_enviar_mensaje);
        lv = (ListView)findViewById(R.id.listaVista);

        ArrayList<String> your_array_list = (new Funciones()).listarCanales();

        // This is the array adapter, it takes the context of the activity as a first // parameter, the type of list view as a second parameter and your array as a third parameter
        ArrayAdapter<String> arrayAdapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(this,android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1, your_array_list);
        lv.setAdapter(arrayAdapter); 

    }

    @Override
    public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
        // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
        getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.enviar_mensaje, menu);
        return true;
    }

    private void showAlert(){
        AlertDialog alertDialog = new AlertDialog.Builder(this).create();
        alertDialog.setTitle("Confirmación.");
        alertDialog.setMessage("Su mensaje ha sido enviado correctamente.");
        alertDialog.setButton("OK", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
           public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {
              // TODO Add your code for the button here.
           }
        });
        // Set the Icon for the Dialog
        alertDialog.setIcon(R.drawable.ic_launcher);
        alertDialog.show();


    }

}
```

Below is my activity_enviar_mensaje:

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:paddingBottom="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
    android:paddingLeft="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
    android:paddingRight="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
    android:paddingTop="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
    tools:context=".EnviarMensaje" >

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/instrucciones"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
        android:text="Escriba el mensaje y luego clickee el canal a ser enviado"
        android:textSize="20sp" />

    <EditText
        android:id="@+id/editText1"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignLeft="@+id/instrucciones"
        android:layout_alignRight="@+id/instrucciones"
        android:layout_below="@+id/instrucciones"
        android:ems="10"
        android:inputType="text" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/textoss"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignLeft="@+id/listaVista"
        android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
        android:text="TextView" />

    <ListView
        android:id="@+id/listaVista"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_above="@+id/textoss"
        android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
        android:layout_below="@+id/editText1" >
    </ListView>



</RelativeLayout>
```

Any help will be much appreciated... Thank you for the time, José.

Comment: Did you declare `err` as a textView?

Comment: Try cleaning your Project (In Eclipse: Project -> Clean)

Comment: Allready did that... no changes...

Comment: does this code calls the onCreate method??
Intent activityChangeIntent = new Intent(FirstActivity.this,           EnviarMensaje.class);
FirstActivity.this.startActivity(activityChangeIntent);

Comment: Post your full activity and layout.

Comment: Can you post your `res/layout/activity_enviar_mensaje.xml` file?

Comment: The id for err is R.id.textoss or R.id.texto ??

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
        ListView lv;
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_enviar_mensaje);
        lv = (ListView)findViewById(R.id.listaVista);
```

You have set the content to activity **TWICE** , That is why your text is not changing because activity is again setting the original layout. Remove the above three lines from the bottom and it will work just fine.

Also after removing the above three lines set the adapter as  `l.setAdapter(arrayAdapter);`

Below is your updated onCreate() Method

```
  @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        l = (ListView)findViewById(R.id.listaVista);    
        t = (EditText)findViewById(R.id.editText1);
        err = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.textoss);
        err.setText("Escriba su mensaje y luego seleccione el canal.");
        l.setOnItemClickListener(new OnItemClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> arg0, View arg1, int arg2, long arg3) {
                String m= t.getText().toString();
                if(m.equals("")){
                    err.setText("Escriba su mensaje y luego seleccione el canal.");
                    return;
                }
                else{
                    showAlert();
                    (new Funciones()).EnviarMensaje(l.getItemAtPosition(arg2).toString(), m);
                    //mostrar mensaje Su mensaje ha sido enviado
                    Intent activityChangeIntent = new Intent(EnviarMensaje.this, FirstActivity.class);
                    EnviarMensaje.this.startActivity(activityChangeIntent);
                }
            }
        });



        ArrayList<String> your_array_list = (new Funciones()).listarCanales();

        // This is the array adapter, it takes the context of the activity as a first // parameter, the type of list view as a second parameter and your array as a third parameter
        ArrayAdapter<String> arrayAdapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(this,android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1, your_array_list);
        l.setAdapter(arrayAdapter); 

    }
```

Comment: MAN! You just gave me the solution!! I've been struggling with this s*** for like 3 days and now its gone!! THANK YOU VERY MUCH!!! YOU ARE THE BESTTT!!!

Comment: Pleasure helping you out :). If your problem got solved You must accept this as an answer by clicking on the tick mark.

Answer (score 0):

There is no `R.id.texto` it the xml file 
change `@+id/textoss` to `@+id/texto` in the layout xml file